# Listing Local Administrators on a Remote Machine with WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I am able to get a list of members of the 'Administrators' group on a remote machine with this function:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GroupMembers(string groupname)
{
    var result = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    try
    {
        var qs = new StringBuilder();
        qs.Append("SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent = \"Win32_Group.Domain='");
        qs.Append(_machineName);
        qs.Append("',Name='");
        qs.Append(groupname);
        qs.AppendLine("'\"");
        var query = new ObjectQuery(qs.ToString()); // SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent = "Win32_Group.Domain='MYMACHINENAME',Name='Administrators'"
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(_scope, query);
        var queryCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var m in queryCollection)
        {
            var path = new ManagementPath(m["PartComponent"].ToString());
            {
                var names = path.RelativePath.Split(',');
                result.Add(names[0].Substring(names[0].IndexOf("=") + 1).Replace("\"", " ").Trim() + "\\" + // Win32_UserAccount.Domain=xxxxxx 
                           names[1].Substring(names[1].IndexOf("=") + 1).Replace("\"", " ").Trim()); // Name=xxxxx

            }
        }
        return result;  // MYMACHINENAME\Administrator,MYDOMAIN\Domain Admins,MYDOMAIN\Dev Service Accounts
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error("Message: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }            
}
```

However, this does not expand the groups returned to list all the individual members. This is effectively the same as `net localgroup Administrators`.

In my example, I'm looking to see if one of the members of `MYDOMAIN\Dev Service Accounts` is an administrator.

How can I adjust my WMI query to expand all the groups to a flat list of usernames?

Comment: I don't know how to query nested groups with WMI, but I can tell you that you will need to query the DC and not just a remote network machine. I personally would use ADSI for querying the DC, but I'm unsure of your requirements.

Comment: @Tim you're right. I had to modify the method in my question to detect if the PartComponent is a group, and if so, get its members recursively from AD and union that with the other results.

Comment: My windows does not allow group nesting so I can't give any integrated code snippet. Here are only hint-like Powershell examples to **get user accouts**: `gwmi -query "Associators Of {Win32_Group.Name='$_group',Domain='$_machine'} Where ResultClass = Win32_UserAccount"` and to **get subgroups** for recurse: `gwmi -query "Associators Of {Win32_Group.Name='$_group',Domain='$_machine'} Where ResultClass = Win32_Group"` You could test your WQL queries using [`Wbemtest.exe` tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46390/WMI-Query-Language-by-Example).

Comment: @JosefZ if only WQL were more like SQL and a simple join were possible

Comment: [While there is no `JOIN` in `WQL`, there is an `ASSOCIATORS OF` query](http://www.ceus-now.com/add-join-and-distinct-support-at-wql/). Try asking Google for something like `WQL "join statement" "Associators Of"` or alike.